# Determining the time given the velocity and speed

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose a man starts to walk at a speed of $4$ km/hour. His velocity after walking $x$ km is given by
$$\frac{40}{10+x}\,\text{km/hour}.$$
I am trying to determine how long he will take to walk $10$ km.

If $v$ denotes the man's velocity, then
$$v(x)=\frac{40}{10+x}.$$ Differentiating or integrating this will give the acceleration or displacement of the man respectively. However, I am unsure how this helps to answer the question.

Comment: Do you want to mean "he will take to walk 10 km"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

By definition

$$v(x)=\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{40}{10+x}$$

So

$$\frac{10+x}{40}dx=dt$$

and by integration,

$$10x+\frac{x^2}{2}=40t$$

So, $$x=10 \text{ Km }\; \implies t=3.75 h$$

Comment: By definition, doesn't $v(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}$?

Comment: In fact, it is $ v(x(t))$

Comment: I am confused. Everywhere I look (including my course notes), velocity is a function of $t$ and not $x$ (which is also a function of $t$).

Comment: Yes, but time $ t$ and $ space $ x $ are related. you can consider the velocity as a function of time $ v(t)$ or of space $ v(x)$.

Comment: Okay. When integrating, do we have a constant of integration (i.e. $+C$)??

Comment: $C=0$ because at $ t=0$, $ x=0$.